# CSS style is not applying to button in React component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have my CSS stylesheet in my index.html file where my React app is loaded. In here I have the following CSS values :

```
#Webshop {
      background-color: white;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
}
```

and

```
#Webshop, button {
      position: relative
      border: 6px solid #232323
      z-index: 2
      padding: 12px 22px
      margin: 0 10px
      box-sizing: border-box
      font-size: 26px
      font-weight: 600
      text-transform: uppercase
      text-decoration: none
      color: #232323
}
```

Webshop is located in a different file that contains this Render method:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div className='Webshop' id='Webshop'>
                <li>
                    <img src="./products.jpeg" width="350" height="350"></img>
                    <button onClick={this.handleClick} className="addit">Add to cart</button>
                    <select id="size" onChange={this.change} value={this.state.value}>
                        <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                        <option value="large">Large</option>
                        <option value="x-large">X-large</option>
                    </select>
                    <img src="./product.jpeg" width="350" height="350"></img>
                </li>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

For some reason the CSS applies to Webshop but not to the button. I have other Components in other files the work also. How can I get the CSS to apply to the button in the Render method?

Comment: Did my answer help at all or is the issue still there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two are critical, the last two are advices.

**1.** remove the comma like so:

```
#Webshop button {
  ...
}
```

**2.** CSS semicolons are a must, while in JavaScript you can omit them, which is being encouraged to do so in [Standard.js](https://standardjs.com/) rules.

**3.** The `img` tags should be self-closing like so: `<img />`. In fact any element without a text within them should follow as well.

**4.** Avoid using IDs in your CSS. Read more about [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: I can't believe I missed such an obvious an obvious mistake. I was totally exhausted when I wrote the code :P But anyways, thank you for the extra tips.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying button style separately. Currently the second style applies to `#webshop` and `button` as you separated them with comma, which is strange, why would you apply same styling to a div element and a button element? Try doing `#webshop button` or `#webshop > button` instead and applying button styles separately.

Also you are missing semicolons at the end of each property in the second style bit which is probably an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Check https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Right now you are applying

```
#Webshop, button {
  position: relative
  border: 6px solid #232323
  z-index: 2
  padding: 12px 22px
  margin: 0 10px
  box-sizing: border-box
  font-size: 26px
  font-weight: 600
  text-transform: uppercase
  text-decoration: none
  color: #232323
}
```

to all elements that either have Webshop id or are buttons,

it should look more like

```
#webshop button {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

probably semicolon in CSS is an issue here, else try to give properties in this particular class(className = "addit")